# How to Use Django Logging with Heroku Papertrail & Waitress

Tags: python, django, logging, heroku, papertrail-app

So I've been trying to get logging to work with Django 1.9.5/Python 3 on a Waitress server running on Heroku, but I have been unable to so far. This is the configuration I have added to my production server Django settings:

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": sys.stdout

        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
        }
    }
}
```

**views.py**

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        logger.info('This is a test INFO error')
        return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Any ideas why this isn't outputting anything into my Heroku Papertrail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logging configuration is set up to capture all logs under the `django` namespace, but in your `views.py`you are using a different namespace set with:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # __name__ resolves to the name of your app.
```

You need to add your app (say it's called `myapp`) to your logging config:

```
"loggers": {
    "django": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
    },
    "myapp": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Also turned out that I needed to log using `logger.warning()` and higher as well